# How to debug Spring Cloud Data flow sink application that is silently failing to write

Tags: spring, debugging, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a sink application that fails to write to db, but am having trouble debugging. Note that I also asked a more specific question [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/cassandra/issues/28), but this question in SO is more general: How should I go about debuggging an SCDF stream pipeline when no errors come up?

### What I'm trying to do

I am trying to follow a tutorial (specifically, [this tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#http-cassandra-local)) which uses some prebuilt applications. Everything is up and running with no error messages, and the source application is correctly writing to Kafka. However, the sink seems to be failing to write anything.

Note that I do see the debugging guide here:

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/troubleshooting/debugging-stream-apps/#sinks

However, this seems to only be relevant when you are writing your own sink.

I am not asking about how to solve my issue per se, but rather about debugging protocol for SCDF apps in general. What is the best way to go about debugging in these kinds of situations where no errors come up but the core functionality isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to view the logs and there are no error messages, the next step is to turn on DEBUG logging for spring-integration. You can set a property on the sink `logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG` that will log any messages coming into the sink.

Comment: Good call. I actually had added this as well, and it didn't really provide any helpful info, but definitely a good debugging step